# Replace existing date with new format

Tags: python, node.js, bash, date

I have a 4GB JSON file in which there are multiple Date fields. the Date format is *`2021-10-15T06:02:50.455Z`*. I want to replace this format with a simple date and time like this *`2021-10-15T06:02:50`*

Is there any way I can do this with **sed** command 
`sed -e 's/[1-9][0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-1][0-9]T[0-3][0-9]:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}.[0-9]\{3\}Z/magic_here/g' test.json`

I'm looking forward to Linus script but node or python also worked.

*PS: regex is working fine*

Comment: IIRC, sed should be able to use some kind of delimiter splitter, so you would be able to get before `.` and after, and only keep the former

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point can you please elaborate further

Comment: nevermind, it was `awk`. Why do you want to use `sed`?

Comment: ```sed``` is just an example. I'm open to any suggestion

Comment: Can you even load and parse that 4GB JSON without your RAM exploding? The JSON format isn't intended to save amounts of data like that. I highly recommend to switch to a format with sequential block read or something (e.g. sqlite), if possible and whatever your working with isn't already in production. Handling JSON files this big will get you in problems constantly.

Comment: file contains multiple JSON objects. An array of JSON @NiklasE.

Comment: @Fazal I already guessed that... how else would you accumulate 4GB of JSON if not as a list of some sort. JSON is really not the fine English way to go here. Use literally anything else. If it has to be JSON then zip or tar multiple JSON files... or something like that

Comment: Actually, the file is MongoDB backup and I can't break it into multiple files because this file use in ETL operations

Comment: Who ever designed this ETL process is a monster.

Answer (score 2):

This look like task where zero-length assertion might be useful, consider following example in `python`:

```
import re
txt = "something 2021-10-15T06:02:50.455Z something"
clean = re.sub(r'(?<=\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\.\d+Z','',txt)
print(clean)
```

output

```
something 2021-10-15T06:02:50 something
```

Explanation: Just remove `\.\d+Z` which are after pattern describing datetime part you want to preserve. Note that I used so called raw-string to make escaping easier, see [`re` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for further discussion. Note that `.` needs to be espaced as it is denoting literal dot. `\d` denotes any digit. This solution might be reworked to any regex tool supporting *positive lookbehind assertion*.

Comment: Thanks, @Daweo for your answer but I think this is not scalable for large files

Answer (score 0):

a simple `sed` would be

```
sed -Ei 's/(T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})[.][0-9]{3}Z/\1/g' file
```